# Comparing rows of the same table with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, rdbms

Here is a table

```
ID | Player | Position | Points
1  | Ryan   | QB       | 75
2  | Matt   | RB       | 80
3  | Mike   | WR       | 66
4  | Jay    | QB       | 71
6  | Alvin  | TE       | 73
7  | Adrian | TE       | 84
8  | Hill   | WR       | 71
9  | Charles| RB       | 53
10 | Bell   | WR       | 87
11 | Rob    | TE       | 49
12 | Alex   | RB       | 92
13 | Drew   | QB       | 84
14 | Mack   | TE       | 59
15 | Nick   | WR       | 33
```

I want to report all the players in the position of the player having highest points and top 2 players of the other positions. In this example, "Alex" has the highest points and is a "RB". So I want to report all players from "RB" and top 2 from "QB", "TE", "WR" and order by points with in each group. I'm using sqlite3. I can do this programmatically using python and sqlite3 but i was wondering if this could be done only using sql

```
ID | Player | Position | Points
12 | Alex   | RB       | 92
2  | Matt   | RB       | 80
9  | Charles| RB       | 53
13 | Drew   | QB       | 84
1  | Ryan   | QB       | 75
10 | Bell   | WR       | 87
8  | Hill   | WR       | 71
7  | Adrian | TE       | 84
6  | Alvin  | TE       | 73
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sqlite3 version 2.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky in "traditional" SQLite.  I would recommend `union all`:

```
with top1 as (
      select t.*
      from t
      order by points desc
      limit 1
     )
select t.*
from t
where t.position = (select t1.position from top1 t1)
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.position <> (select t1.position from top1 t1) and
      (select count(*)
       from t t2
       where t2.position = t.position and
             t2.points >= t.points
      ) <= 2;
```

This assumes that the `points` values are unique.  Ties are much harder to deal with in SQLite.

I might recommend that you consider upgrading to SQLite version 3.25.0 or use another database.  Such a query would be much simpler using ISO/ANSI standard window functions.

With window functions, it would look like:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by position order by points desc) as seqnum,
             first_value(position) over (order by points desc) as first_position
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2 or position = first_position
```